# Displaying multiple records of same type order by value and then order by type using mysql - is it even possible

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, multiple-columns, multiple-tables

[image]

What I want to do is order by all the records by years experience so I get the highest number on top. Then take the vendor type of the top record and group all the records with that vendor type together. So if in the table picture 11 is the highest number and its vendor type is 1. It should group all the vendor types 1 together and still in descending order. Then list the other vendor types like in this case its 2 and its respective record(s) again in descending order.

Following is what I am trying to do

SELECT `usid` , `userskills`.`vid` , `appid` , `appversion` , `yearsexperience` , `vendor_type`
FROM (
`userskills`
)
JOIN `vendor` ON `vendor`.`vid` = `userskills`.`vid`
WHERE `uid` = '734'
ORDER BY `yearsexperience` DESC , `vendor_type` DESC

so in this case I want the result as

[image]

i hope it makes sense

Comment: Not that it's directly relevant to this problem but anyway, see normalization

Comment: I am afraid I am to far ahead in the project now to go back do database design changes.

Can it be done at code level

Comment: No. Normalisation is fundamental to working efficiently with relational data.

Comment: i agree with that. Unfortunately that is how i have inherited the code and database.